# how does one create a .po file

Tags: csv, translation

I know I can use poedit to do this. I can't seem to find any other tools for the job. Also, is there a similar tool that scans my code and makes a csv file for translation? I'd rather use CSV actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **xgettext** to scan C/C++ source code and extract gettext strings. For python code, use **pygettext.py** instead (it ships with Python).

Comment: I see that xgettext can handle PHP as well, which is what I'm after. Thanks!